# Shell Script Cannot detect other processes unless I resave it

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a script that is to be called when we want to reboot the system. All it does is stop a few processes before we call 'reboot'. The script is installed using a deb, along with whatever other .jars and files the system requires. When I run it from the command line as follows:

```
sudo /bin/bash Shutdown.sh
```

Then it returns the following:

```
stop: Unknown job: process1
stop: Unknown job: process2
```

before rebooting. The two processes are NOT being stopped before the reboot call is done. 
This is what the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash 
stop "process1"
stop "process2"
reboot
```

Now for the weird part: if I open the file (I am using WinSCP to view the files remotely, the files are on a Linux machine) and then save it and rerun the command it works perfectly.

This led me to believe that it is a permissions issue. But running

```
ls -l Shutdown.sh
```

Shows that the file has the same permissions before. The only difference is that after I have resaved it, the file is 2 bytes smaller than previously. I'm thinking it might be a hidden character issue - but I cant seem to solve the problem. It is important for the file to work after it has been placed there by a deb install.

(Oh, and also, modifying and resaving the file using nano didn't help either. It still displays the same issue as described at first.)

Comment: This is probably an issue with line endings. Make sure your windows editor is not using Windows line endings (`\r\n`/CRLF), but unix line feeds (`\n`/LF).

Comment: Thank you for the quick help :D! The thing is that the Windows editor actually fixes the problem. If I were to edit it using nano then it doesn't fix the problem. This is a really weird issue :(

Comment: Is the code above what the script _looks like_ or what the skript _exactly is_?

Comment: Also, thank you to John for editing my text to look better! I really appreciate it. I'm still a bit of a noob when it comes to using this site.

Comment: Its what it looks like. I just replaced the names of the processes since I don't think my boss would appreciate it if we used the real application names in there. Basically the names are productname-process

Comment: Try to compare the "fixed" and broken version using `diff [file1][file2]`, and if that does not help use `hexdump -C [file]` for each file and find the difference. Using the `file` command might also give a hint what's going wrong (it must be some encoding issue).

Comment: Ah! After using the file command, I got the following output: Shutdown.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators. It seems you have been right all along :D! Now I'm struggling with the editor to make it work correctly. I'll give an update tomorrow on what happened.

Comment: A very wild guess: You somewhat copied the process names including the malicious `\r` from the windows machine. By changing it on the linux box, you've now got different line endings. By saving it again from the windows editor, `\r` gets added everywhere which is again accepted by the bash. Usually you can configure your editor to store "UTF-8 + Unix-Linefeeds" somewhere, maybe by selecting the format in the "Save as" dialog.

Comment: Ok so I did everything I possibly could to get the file to have the correct line ending. It refused! Seems mercurial changes the line endings to be different. Luckily I found an old script in a different part of the project. I copied, pasted and modified and now everything works fine. Thank you for all the help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: For future reference, you should be able to use the **dos2unix** command on your file to fix the line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your script, use `kill` instead of `stop` as it can't identify process by name

```
#!/bin/bash 
kill `pidof process1`
kill `pidof process2`
reboot
```